# Bitlocker Auto-Unlock C drive with TPM

Tags: bitlocker, tpm

I wanted to enable auto-unlock on C drive with TPM. When I click on enable bitlocker on C Drive, it shows me only 2 options

- Insert a USB drive
- Enter a password

I do not see any option which says

- Let bitlocker automatically unlock my drive.

I have enabled the Group Policy **Require additional authentication at startup.**

I have enabled TPM at hardware level as well.

Please help.

Comment: For completeness, can you update your post with output from `Get-Tpm`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it on my own. The issue was my C drive was in MBR partition type. I had to convert it to GPT partition type and change the BIOS to UEFI mode, followed by a restart and it worked.